Filter out multiple rows in a data.frame
I have created the following data.frame
mannen <- c(-99997, 1,2, -99997)
vrouwen <- c(1,2, -99997, 3)
df_test <- data.frame(mannen, vrouwen)
df_test$mannen <- as.numeric(df_test$mannen)
df_test$vrouwen <- as.numeric(df_test$vrouwen)

I would like to create a data.frame that only shows rows without -99997 (so expected result is 1 row). I tried to filter using dplyr:
df_filter <- df_test %>%
 filter(!(mannen == -99997) && !(vrouwen == -99997)) 

However this one does not work. Any thoughts on what goes wrong?

But dplyr::filter(df_test, mannen != -99997, vrouwen != -99997) or dplyr::filter(df_test, mannen != -99997 & vrouwen != -99997) does. Read the docs!

Also, you don't need as.numeric. Check it with str(df_test).

In dplyr you just need a single "&" (instead of double as you used), a comma will do too, as someone mentioned above :)
Try:
df_filter <- df_test %>%
 filter(!(mannen == -99997) & !(vrouwen == -99997)) 


library(tidyverse)

df_test
#>   mannen vrouwen
#> 1 -99997       1
#> 2      1       2
#> 3      2  -99997
#> 4 -99997       3

df_test %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~.x != -99997))
#>   mannen vrouwen
#> 1      1       2

base
fltr <- apply(df_test, 1, function(x) prod(x != -99997) == 1L)

df_test[fltr]

